TCPDUMP not in line with MTR/ping result
I am trying to find some connection issues with my local lan. New to tcpdump so help needed!
The coomand run on my test VM which is 192.168.30.18:
tcpdump "host 192.168.0.100 or host 192.168.32.1" -w capture.cap

where 192.168.0.100 and 192.168.32.1 are physical devices.
Two MTR ran in two terminal gave me 7% packets loss for 0.100, no loss for 32.1.
TCPDUMP file attached shown that both 0.100 and 30.1 have quite alot packets loss, but no loss for 32.1 was shown by MTR.
Any thing I need to know to understand this inconsistancy?
Thanks guys,
YH
the screen capture of the Wireshark display for the tcpdump file


for 32.1: there's no loss for 32.1 in shown tcpdump
for 0.100: more likely replies were received on another interface by mtr, but tcpdump was run on one interface only

